# How to get array of model objects using resolver?

Tags: angular

I use resolver to get data from server

```html
import {Resolve, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Town} from "../_models/town";

@Injectable()
export class TownsListResolver implements Resolve<any>{

 constructor(private http: HttpClient,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
 }

 resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<Town[]> {
  return this.http.get('/api/towns');
 }
}
```

and i wont to convert array of objects like this :

```
data['towns']['models'].forEach((item) => {
            this.townsList.push(item);
        });
```

which rxJs or basic angular functions i should use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do the following :

```
resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<Town[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/towns').pipe(
        map(p => p['towns']['models'])
    );
}
```

That way, you keep on exposing an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tap()`.

For example:

```
.pipe(
 tap(data => this.townsList = [...data['towns']['models']]
)
```